# Xcode: Text Label Text Not Changing When Tapping Table Cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a view controller called `ViewController` with a container view in it that embeds a table view controller. When I press a table cell, I want a label in `ViewController` to change text based on which cell is tapped.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
int row = (int)indexPath.row;
NSString *textlabel = self.array[row];
NSLog(@"%@", textlabel);
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
controller.viewBarLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textlabel];

}
```

I checked using the NSLog and it does log the correct string from the array. The problem is the label text does not change. Yes, I did import `ViewController.h`.

Help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the ViewController instead of using the same instance.

You don't need a view controller object to control objects inside the view controller you are controlling with 'self'.

Remove this..

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

You can use this..

```
self.viewBarLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textlabel];
```

Comment: use this... self.viewBarLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textlabel];

Comment: you don't need another view controller object to control the view controller you are in now.. you can do that using self... my bad

Comment: Guys, im working with a seperate .m and .h file than my viewcontroller. I have a container view that embeds a tableview controller with its own files.

Comment: ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You should not initialize ViewController again. The `UILabel` in the ViewController in your case can be accessed with `self`.

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
controller.viewBarLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textlabel];
```

Replace the above 2 lines with

```
self.viewBarLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textlabel];
```

Comment: Im not in ViewController's .h and .m file. Self does not work.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys,

I never found the actual answer so i deleted the container view containing the table view and made a table view with the view controller as delegate. That worked because i was controlling the table view's action from within my controller.
Thanks for all the help!